# Bit shifting in C is different from PHP

Tags: php, c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have a question about a small piece of code in C to make the same piece of code work in PHP, it has to do with a bit shift and I can't figure out what's wrong.

**C:**

```
unsigned u = 3910796769;
u += u << 8;
printf("%u\n",u); 
//Result : 52422369
```

**PHP:**

```
$u = 3910796769;
$u += $u << 8;
printf("%u\n",$u);
//Result : 1005074769633
```

Comment: Can you try `$u += ($u << 8);` ? It might be a precedence issue.

Comment: Change `u` to be `unsigned long long` and use `%llu` to print it. Then you will get the same result as PHP: https://ideone.com/42FAYk

Comment: 3910796769 is a 32-bit number.  So in C, assuming 32-bit ints, when you shift it left by 8 bits, you're going to lose some of it.

Comment: @SteveSummit More important is that `u` is of 32-bit type  (likely). A number can be extended to any number of bits.

Comment: If you want make PHP behave as C, you can "manually truncate" the result to 32 bits: `$u = $u & 0xFFFFFFFF`: https://ideone.com/U0mvCE

Comment: @Eugene Sh Thanks for the reply, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to select elements from an array filled with 32-bit values using a specific formula.
The answer from @Eugene Sh helped me do this in PHP.

```
$u = 3910796769;
$u += $u << 8;
$u = $u & 0xFFFFFFFF
printf("%u\n",$u);
//Result : 52422369
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `unsigned` in C is 32bit, you cannot even shift the number you provided once without triggering an overflow, but you have shifted it 8 times and added one more time, like multiplying the number by `257`, you should get the result mod `2^32 == 4294967296`:

```
unsigned u = 3910796769;
u += u << 8;
```

this should be `256*u + u == 257 * u == 1005074769633 ~= 52422369 (mod 4294967296)`
You can test it.

```
[...]
//Result : 52422369  /* correct (mod 2^32) */
```

PHP probably uses 64bit integers for the operations, and the result properly fits in 64bit.

```
$u = 3910796769;
$u += $u << 8;
printf("%u\n",$u);
//Result : 1005074769633
```

But if you try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint64_t u = 3910796769;
    u += u << 8;
    printf("%Lu\n", u); 
    //Result : 1005074769633
}
```

you will get the correct result.